# Using register in playbook for multiple clients

Tags: linux, shell, ansible

### Hello Everyone.

First task in my playbook will be executed in server.
 Second task will be executed in clients. ##

#### First task : generate token numbers for all clients listed in inventory

```
- hosts: Server
  vars:
    clients:
      - clientA
      - ClientB
  tasks:
   - name: generate ticket on server and save it as a variable
     shell: /path/to/bin ticket {{ clients }} 
     register: ticket
```

### Second task: Make clients to use generated token specific to them.

(Example: ClientA should take ticket {{ hostvars['server']['ticket'][0]['stdout'] }}

output example for one client: "stdout": "9338e126e8dd454820870b3ba19f5344334c8b1d" ##

Note: below play is for one client

```
- hosts: ClientA
  tasks:
  shell: /path/to/bin --key /path/to/store-key/ticket.key --ticket {{ hostvars['server']['ticket']['stdout'] }}
```

#### Above plays works completely fine with one client but no idea to write play for multiple clients (in loop)

Need inputs to write shell value for below play (for multiple clients) ##

```
- hosts: "{{ clients }}"
  vars:
    clients:
      - clientA
      - ClientB
  tasks:
  shell: /path/to/bin --key /path/to/store-key/ticket.key --ticket !!!!!!!!Please your input here !!!!!!!!!
```

### How can we achieve it?

##

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You will get a much better chance to gain attention if you format your question correctly. You can click on the edit button below your question and have a look at the formatting aids at the right of the screen. You should pay a particular attention to your code blocks. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is to

1. Add to hosts in `clients` group index of the host

```yaml
clients:
  hosts:
    clientA:
      uid: 0
      <etc>
    clientB:
      uid: 1
      <etc>
```

2. Add loop to server part (see below)
3. Address the client's token by its `uid` as array index in `ticket` variable

```yaml
- hosts: serverA
  tasks:
   - name: generate ticket on server and save it as a variable
     shell: /path/to/bin ticket {{ item }} 
     register: ticket
     with_items:
      - "{{ groups['clients'] }}"

- hosts: clients
  tasks:
   - name: checkticket
     shell: /path/to/bin --key /path/to/store-key/ticket.key --ticket {{ hostvars['serverA']['ticket']['results'][uid]['stdout'] }}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy..., i used another way. Added deligate_to for the token generation task and modified playbook with single play.. which was fine !! Cheers..